# Receiving "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." error with my Firebase API

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm making an API with firebase, however, whenever I try and call it through Postman, I receive a "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." error.

Here's a bit of my index.js. I set it to a basic one for now.

```js
//Functions
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();


//Routes
app.get('/api/test', (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).send("Hello! You have reached my Test API. All it does is this!")
});



//Export the api to Firebase cloud functions
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

It's being hosted with localhost for now. I can provide more info if needed.

I've proofread the code, and nothing seems to be wrong.

I've tried many other instances of this question, and have had no success. I'm happy to share some other documents

Here is my Package.json

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "20"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Here's a screenshot of my Postman:
[Postman Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/momDl.png)

And here's the response of the API in raw

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 Copyright 2020 Google LLC

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
        function _gtag() {
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      _gtag('js', new Date());
    </script>
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#681da8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#681da8" />
    <meta name="description" content="A local-first UI for Firebase Emulator Suite." />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json?v=3" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png?v=3" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png?v=3" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png?v=3" />
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg?v=3" color="#681da8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=3" />
    <title>Firebase Emulator Suite</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto Mono:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- More icons needed for Storage, in addition to the base ones above. -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Extended" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.c2583d42.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.58ca09f7.css">
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      See README.md at repository root for how to start development or build a production bundle.
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: Where do you see this error?

Comment: @GabeRAMturn I've added my package.json

Comment: @GregFenton I see the error testing the API in Postman

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your Postman showing the request and that error.

Comment: That is the "Preview".  What does the "Raw" show?

Comment: I inserted it below the image

Comment: It looks like you're accessing `/test` in postman, but your end point is set to `/api/test`. The "error" is just the default page saying it doesn't have javascript, which makes sense as it's being displayed via postman.

Comment: @Ouroborus Oops. I did change that, but it didn't fix the issue sadly. Exactly the same message